# Secure login script on Google Code - without mail form field?

Tags: php, security, authentication, google-code

I need a login system on my site.
[On this page](https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-secure-login-script-example/source/browse/branches/index.php), I found the "secure login scripts" - this is the header of the page.

But there is no:

- mail verification,
- mail field on the form (duplicate mails are allowed),
- limit for false login try,
- restriction for duplicates IP addresses.
- no captcha...

Could someone comment  - is this script really secure  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the *official google page*. Google Code is something like GitHub - any developer can host his project there.

As for the script.. If you don't feel it's secure enough, why don't you make it secure then?

Comment: Sergej, thanks. The first part of your answer clarify enough.